Getting ancestors from hierarchies
I have this schema :
create table t_hierarchy
(
    id          number  ,
    id_sup      number  ,
    id_type number
)
;
insert into t_hierarchy values (1, null, 1);
insert into t_hierarchy values (2, 1, 1);

insert into t_hierarchy values (3, 2, 0);
insert into t_hierarchy values (4, 3, 0);
insert into t_hierarchy values (5, 4, 0);
-- ----
insert into t_hierarchy values (6, 2, 1);

insert into t_hierarchy values (7, 6, 0);
insert into t_hierarchy values (8, 7, 0);
-- ----
insert into t_hierarchy values (9, 2, 1);

insert into t_hierarchy values (10, 9, 0);
insert into t_hierarchy values (11, 10, 0);
-- ----
insert into t_hierarchy values (12, 2, 1);

insert into t_hierarchy values (13, 12, 0);
insert into t_hierarchy values (14, 13, 0);
insert into t_hierarchy values (15, 14, 0);

insert into t_hierarchy values (16, 12, 0);
insert into t_hierarchy values (17, 16, 0);
insert into t_hierarchy values (18, 17, 0);

It represents a hierarchy between objects.
My goal is to get, for each id that has id_type equals to zero, its last ancestor.
For example, if we take ids in (3,4,5) then there last ancestor that has id_type = 0 is 3.
Here is the desired output :
id  id_sup  id_type last_ancestor
--  ------  ------- -------------
1           1       
2   1       1   
3   2       0       3
4   3       0       3
5   4       0       3
6   2       1       
7   6       0       7
8   7       0       7
9   2       1       
10  9       0       10
11  10      0       10
12  2       1       
13  12      0       13
14  13      0       13
15  14      0       13
16  12      0       16
17  16      0       16
18  17      0       16

Thanks in advance,

Assuming that your hierarchy is a tree then you can start from each id and backtrack up the tree while the id_type is 0 until you reach the earliest ancestor (which will be the leaf of the hierarchy as you are backtracking):
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT id_sup AS id_sup,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT id_type AS id_type,
       CASE id_type WHEN 0 THEN id END AS last_ancestor
FROM   t_hierarchy t
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR id_sup = id
AND    PRIOR id_type = 0
AND    id_type = 0

Which outputs:



ID
ID_SUP
ID_TYPE
LAST_ANCESTOR




1
null
1
null


2
1
1
null


3
2
0
3


4
3
0
3


5
4
0
3


6
2
1
null


7
6
0
7


8
7
0
7


9
2
1
null


10
9
0
10


11
10
0
10


12
2
1
null


13
12
0
13


14
13
0
13


15
14
0
13


16
12
0
16


17
16
0
16


18
17
0
16



fiddle

Thanks a lot for the valuable answer.
It's really not obvious and not intuitive to write such queries.
